# How do I change faces indices count in blender

Tags: 3d, blender

I have a .obj folder which have faces values listed like this:
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4/4

Is it possible to change the facing indices to:
1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3

I heard using blender it is possible to do so, may I ask for instructions on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I import my object into blender, and I click on it, and go into edit mode (Shortcut press TAB), then press ctrl+T, it will fix the issue, and I can then export it.